# SourceTree: Setup Assistant Frozen

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

After updating to the newest version SourceTree application become unusable.

[image]

I tried several times to delete application and reinstall it, but result is always the same.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: downgrade to last version. You are not the only one with this issue: https://twitter.com/hashtag/sourcetree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the current version.